# Matlab, for loop numbering issue to load images files

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I want to use matlab for loop to load .bmp images into row vector. The looping and filenames are not looping according to sequence. Below are my codes and example of the files name. I was trying to figure out the problems, and I found that, the file number will start loop and read from 1, then straight to 10,11,12,13,14,15 until 19, then only loop from 2, then 21,22,23,24, until 29, then only 3, then 31.... The filename read only the front number. May I know how to solve this problem? I wish to loop the file from img1,img2,img3,img4,img5,img6,img7,img8,img9,img10,img11

```
%file names : (30 image files)
%img1.bmp - img30.bmp

%Matlab codes start here :
train_img_num = numel(train_files);
train_img = [];
for i=1:1:train_img_num
     number = num2str(i);
    filename = fullfile(userFolder2, train_files(i).name);
    img = reshape((mat2gray(im2double(imread(filename))))',1,180000);
    train_img(i,:) = img(:);
    clear img;
end
```

Comment: The loop follows the order in `{train_files.name}`. Also, if your files are names file1, ...,file10, ...file20 etc... the is order respects dictionary sorting. Rename the files to file01, file02 etc...

Comment: may i know how to solve the problem by loading the files according to the whole number but not only the front number?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like @OlegKomarov is probably correct: your struct array `train_files` is not sorted according to the `'name'` field. You could [`sort`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sort.html) it before looping like this:

```
[~,idx] = sort({train_files.name});
train_files = train_files(idx);
```

or possibly

```
[~,idx] = sort([train_files.name]);
train_files = train_files(idx);
```

This [blog post from The Mathworks](http://blogs.mathworks.com/pick/2010/09/17/sorting-structure-arrays-based-on-fields/) has other options.

Another option is not use the struct and directly write the file name using [`sprintf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html):

```
filename = fullfile(userFolder2, sprintf('img%d.bmp',i));
```